# How to wrap newline with same first pattern?

Tags: regex

How to wrap this example:

1. As business unit head
2. As partnership in a business and with number

   4 of partnership venture
3. As per corporate sales
4. As business unit head
5. As partnership in a business and with number

   10 of partnership venture
6. As per corporate sales

Expected output would be:

1. As business unit head
2. As partnership in a business and with number 4 of partnership venture
3. As per corporate sales
4. As business unit head
5. As partnership in a business and with number 10 of partnership venture
6. As per corporate sales

I've tried `([a-z]) \r\n([0-9])` this would wrap those numbers with dot(.). I would only like to wrap numbers without dot(.) Like the expected output above.

Any help is very much appreciated. Sorry im new to regex.

Comment: so you want to match any breaks occuring between 2 numers with a dot? Am I correct?

Comment: 2 numers without a dot sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\r?\s{1,}(\d{1,}[^.].*)` should do what you're looking for. Afterwards you can replace the entire match with the first match in the pattern (`$1`)

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot @philipproplesch but can you define how this works? regex101 must be a friend but i needed someone to break down the details of your solution above. If you have time sir, please?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly as I wrote in a reply to your question
I think this regex will suit your needs

```
(\n|\r)(?![0-9]+\.)
```

Comment: not a solution sir, i need to wrap the numbers in newline but not the numbers with dot(.)

Comment: @Lucas think you missunderstand what my expression really does, check the above sample for a clear view